# Can one go to the movies on Shabbat if they order and print the tickets ahead of time?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mitzvah, performance-entertainment

Can one go to the movies on Shabbat if they order and print the tickets ahead of time?

Regardless of whether one should be studying Torah and praying for sake of piety, would one be defying any miztvah?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65691/television-on-shabbos

Comment: Watching TV on Shabbat is still not defying any mitzvah per se though, it's just that there are probably more respectably deemable ways to spend your Shabbat

Comment: You need to specify that it is inside an eruv to allow the tickets to be carried (though the ticket might be muktzah).

Comment: Is there anything else besides that that could be problematic?

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't see how the ticket could be muktzeh if going to the movies is permitted.

Comment: Other than carrying, which is not an issue within the eruv, the only other item I can think of is that going to the movies is a "weekday activity". I.e., certain activities come into the category of "not in keeping with the sanctity of Shabbat." I assume that the theater itself presents no "electronic" issues such as activating the lobby door when you enter the place.

Comment: @Daniel It might be muktzah because it is solely used for an *improper activity*

Comment: At the theatres near me, an employee tears the ticket as you enter.  I don't know if cooperating in that could cause any transgression to reflect back on the movie-goer (if the employee is a non-Shabbat-observing Jew), or if we say that he would have torn somebody's ticket anyway and it just happened to be yours.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The presentation of the ticket is what allows you into the movie. The tearing of the ticket does not. In terms of whether this would be considered your causing someone else to do a melacha for you, MAY make a difference, here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio they tear it for their own sake (so the ticket can't be reused), not yours, arguably.

Comment: Tearing for destruction is not a melachah. It is a Rabbinical restriction though. So to say that the employee ripping it is in any way connected to you (which it seems he is doing because the boss made that policy not the movie goer) doesn't sound like a problem.

Comment: Isn't there a concept of inevitable outcome?  If I go to the movie they *will* tear the ticket,  and they did so because I presented it.  Maybe it's fine;  I brought it up not to start a discussion in comments but so that answers could consider whether it matters. We should probably continue in chat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Television on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65691/television-on-shabbos)

Comment: Uvdin d'chol [15 chars]