# Musical Performances and Shows on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, music, performance-entertainment

There is a musical performance with free admission on Shabbat with, presumably, no Jewish performers.

Can one enjoy it without violating Shabbat prohibitions? Or will this be benefiting from someone who does a Melacha on Shabbat?

Comment: A Gentile is allowed to do melachah on Shabbos. He isn't doing melachah just for you, but for the Gentile crowd. He also might not be doing any melachah (not all instruments require melachah)

Comment: There is a concept of *uvda d’chol*, weekdays activities technically authorized on Shabbos but which break the concept of Shabbos. Similar to watching a TV you would have left on. We actually have a question on this: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65691/11501